# Couchbase store only one revision

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

Is it possible to store only one revision of each document in Couchbase so that it doesn't inflate  after each update using `set`? This question is interesting in context of Couchbase Lite too.

Comment: So Couchbase *does* only store one revision of a document, unless you explicitly are performing some kind of manual revisioning (say with a version suffix on the key). What inflation are you seeing?

Comment: Hmm, probably this is related to Couchbase Lite and Sync Gateway only. For example, I have a script which sets or deletes some docs to `default` bucket. Also I have a `sync_gateway` bucket connected. Imagine I import 1000 docs, then remove them, then import again — `default` would have 1000 docs and `sync_gateway` 3000+n. And even more, mobile apps would try to download all 3000 docs (3 revisions) from `sync_gateway`

Comment: I understand why this happens (Sync Server may want to clients who downloaded first revision that docs were deleted in second), but for new clients it probably should offer only newest revision, however it would send all 3000 docs to CBL client!